# SQL with Visual C#: Incorrect syntax near ''

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I keep on getting an sql exception error that states:

> Incorrect syntax near 'Bsc.'.

This error happens at the line I have indicated with a comment.

`'Bsc'` is the value of val1 that has been parsed?

I have tried all means to resolve the error but I am not sure what's the problem,

```
public Marksheet(object val1, object val2, object val3, object val4)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    string connectionString = null;
    SqlConnection conn; 
    connectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated security=SSPI;database=jms";

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select s.course_abbreviation, s.course_name, s.month_of_admission, s.year_of_admission from students s where exists (select 1 from units_allocation ua where s.course_abbreviation=ua.'"+val1+"' and s.course_name=ua.'"+val2+"' and s.month_of_admission=ua.'"+val3 +"' and s.year_of_admission=ua.'"+val4+"'", connectionString);

    conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
    DataTable dt5 = new System.Data.DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt5);    // Error occurs here
    gridControl1.DataSource = dt5;
}
```

The sql query is an inner join between students table and units_allocated table.

I am fetching records from students table where the 4 fields are equal...

The above function is in different form and which is called by the following:

```
object val1;
    object val2;
    object val3;
    object val4;
    private void gridView1_RowClick(object sender, RowClickEventArgs e)
    {
        int rowHandle = e.RowHandle;
        val1 = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gridView1.Columns[2]);
        val2 = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gridView1.Columns[3]);
        val3 = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gridView1.Columns[4]);
        val4 = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(rowHandle, gridView1.Columns[5]);

        Marksheet marksheet = new Marksheet(val1, val2, val3, val4);
        marksheet.Show();
    }
```

I want to output a gridview/table in the second form with student records having 4 field values to the one I am clicking.

I am passing column values and expecting records from students table with fields registration_no, first_name, last_name, cat1_marks, cat2_marks, exam_marks and overall_marks.

Comment: [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) says "Hi".

Comment: So your query string should really contain `s.course_abbrevation=ua.'Bsc'`?

Comment: There are *several* things very wrong with this code.  You have no control over what types are even being passed to this method and assume they'll convert nicely to strings, you're directly concatenating input to SQL code and *executing that input as code* (which means your query could be literally *anything*, which you're not bothering to debug and find out what it is), and I can't quite figure out what you expect something like `ua.'something'` to even *mean*.

Comment: [Parameterized SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738521%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: Looking at you query, you should probably be doing an inner join between students and units_allocated. Can you provide some sample data and an example of what you would like returned?

Comment: yes, the inner inner join is quite paramout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are trying to match on column names and your `val` variables contain the names of those columns, so you need to remove the single quotes - the quotes are only necessary if trying to match on an explicit value.

```
where s.course_abbreviation=ua."+val1+"
```

so your query will look like this:

```
SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(
"Select s.course_abbreviation, s.course_name, s.month_of_admission, s.year_of_admission " + 
"from students s " + 
"where exists (select 1 from units_allocation ua " +
"where s.course_abbreviation=ua."+val1+" and s.course_name=ua."+val2+" and s.month_of_admission=ua."+val3 +" and s.year_of_admission=ua."+val4+""
, connectionString);
```

Of course the usual [**"you should never inject SQL parameters that way!"**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35136896/sql-with-visual-c-incorrect-syntax-near/35139105?noredirect=1#comment57993771_35136896) warning applies.

---

**Edit:**

if my previous assumption was incorrect, then the other issue you have is the table alias in your `where` clause - just remove it. But if you do that then your inner select still looks really wrong*. If we distill it down to just a straight SQL statement we have:

```
select s.course_abbreviation, s.course_name, s.month_of_admission, s.year_of_admission  
from students s 
where exists (
                 select 1 
                 from units_allocation ua 
                 where s.course_abbreviation='val1' 
                 and s.course_name='val2' 
                 and s.month_of_admission='val3' 
                 and s.year_of_admission='val4'
             )
```

This is a bit of a funny way to try to do an inner join. Why would you select from the `units_allocation` table by comparing `students` columns to explicit values?

You may be stuck because there is no direct link from `units_allocation` back to `students`, - in this case you will need to join via other tables as well. Your inner join should look something like this:

```
select s.*, ua.*
from students s
    inner join units_allocation ua
    on ua.[foreign_key_column] = s.[primary_key_column]
where s.course_abbreviation='val1'
and s.course_name='val2'
...etc...
```

Using an `exists` could be counterproductive the way you have it - it will return all rows in the outer query if the `exists` condition is satisfied.

*<sub>I'm a SQL generalist, not a specialist. So this `exists()` syntax for achieving an inner join may be totally wrong, I don't know unless I try it - which I haven't (and I've never written a join in that way).</sub>

Comment: You can use [`quotename(`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) to help mitigate sql injection attacks. However you must add a layer of inderection and run your query from a `@sql = '...where s.course_abbreviation=ua.' + QUOTENAME(@val1) + 'and s.course_name=ua.' + QUOTENAME(@val2) + ' and ...'` to build the query in to a temp variable then do a `exec sp_executesql @sql` to execute it

Comment: The OP isn't actually comparing column names as he stated here : "I am fetching records from students table where the 4 fields are equal..."

Comment: @LeWoogush There is no other reason for him to have the table alias there then. He's either mistakenly used the table alias, (in which case it should be removed), or the alias is correct (in which case the single quotes should be removed). So it's a guessing game about what he actually intended.

Comment: @slugster it is actually clear from the getRowCellValue(s) in the second code part and "The sql query is an inner join between students table and units_allocated table." that the user is taking an entry from a table to find all data in the other table that contains the same content as these 4 cells.

Comment: @slugster The first error resolved but another has come up: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'and'. --Any ideas?

Comment: @LeWoogush Then explain the statement *The sql query is an inner join between students table and units_allocated table.*? Why would he attempt an inner join using  **from units_allocation ua 
where s.course_abbreviation='"+val1+"'**  ? In any case the query is messed up, if my answer is not helpful then so be it.

Comment: @slugster not trying to be rude, I think he was attempting a join on four fields because he couldn't use an Id?

Comment: @LeWoogush No problems, this is just part of the guessing game we sometimes have to play, where part of the code/question contradicts another part. FWIW my original answer was effectively the same as yours and then I changed it based on a re-read of the question.

Comment: @Valentine Could you perhaps edit your question to add a little more details about what the query is expected to return and what exactly are you passing as parameters? (values or column names)

Answer (score 0):

```
where s.course_abbreviation=ua.'"+val1+"'
```

Remove the ua. and it should fix it.

using x. in front of a variable in SQL tries to find the defination of a column.